# jquery ajax asynchronous requests error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

at the beginning I would like to say sorry for my bad english.

jquery v2.0.0 in Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox, Opera last versions

Today I had a problem

```
timer_multy_update = setInterval(
    function()
    {
        $.get(
           'test.php',
           function (result){
              parseAndUpdateData(result);
           },
           "json"
        );
    }, 500)
```

The problem is that if the server hangs (I don't know how to say it correctly), i.e. time to get answer from the server more the 0,5 second, but timer not stay and continues to send request, so before the server answer it can be send 2-4 request, all this answer return for a little time and, now a problem, in firebug all request correct, but variable result contains only one answer from the first answer from the server. maybe I did not express myself clearly, I want to say that 2-4 request to the server return different answer, but in result gets all 2-4 times the first answer from the server, and it is big problem.

I tried to find information on the Internet, but found nothing.

I do not know why but the first thought was that the error in jquery, I began to look at the source code, and found some mention about heder and it's hashes.
So i try to change my script and find to way

```
$.get
(
    '/php/mine/update_cells.php',
    't='+Math.random(),
    function (result)
    {
        parseAndUpdateData(result);
    },
    "json"
);
```

it works correctly
so I want to now, bug it is or my mistake and not understanding

Comment: because you added math.random, url is different every time so resource is not cashed by browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a bug, it's caching. It's a lot more efficient for a browser to cache a resource for a while then have to go and get it every time someone wants it. This is fine for static resources, i.e. ones that don't change much but for a web service that returns different results frequently for the same URL you will want to disable the caching. If you control the server side code, add a `Cache-Control: no-cache` header to the response. You can disable caching in your jQuery but as far as I know, you have to use the `ajax()` function - there's no way to do it with `get()`.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/php/mine/update_cells.php",
  success: function(result){
     parseAndUpdateData(result);
  },
  cache: false,
  dataType: 'json'
});
```

Comment: I add header, but it doesn't has effect
`Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:id=Xb97FxROHEni7bGg; k=L4UHWE47zPhO2rEa
Pragma:no-cache
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.95 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest`

Comment: the second way work same as my)
/php/land/update_cells.php?_=1377328853001
that is sended by $.ajax with cache: false

Comment: @user2713024 You need to add it to the response headers. Those look like request headers.

Comment: `header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache");`
this doesn't has effect, maybe I don't understand you